# Python, Tkinter, Function to destroy Images. (multiple arguments)

Tags: python, function, parameters, tkinter, destroy

ive been making a program in Tkinter and basically i want to remove all the images that have been placed on the window to be removed. Seen as the function i have created (or tried to :P) is in charge of clearing the window i need it to be able to remove whatever i want it to from any point in the program.

Theres 2 images on this window, img and img1. After 5000 seconds? (Another thing im not sure on but havent looked at that bit yet) The timer will run out and lead to the function. However i seem to be formatting the function wrong.

As you can see, i tried using (*A) But that appears to just be for strings for printing and such and doesnt recognise the .destroy(). Another thing i tried was to have the function like:

```
def removewidgets(A)(B)(C)(D):
    A.destroy()
    B.destroy()
    C.destroy()
    D.destroy()
    return;
```

But i am convinced this is a terrible method and it didnt work anyway hah.
Really hope someone can solve my issue, many thanks!

Heres the code.

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
#______________________________________________________________________________________
SWH = Tk()
SWH.geometry("1024x950+130+0")
SWH.title("ServiceWhiz.")
#_______________________________________________________________#GlobalFunctions#______
#ClearAllWidgets
def removewidgets(*A):
    A.destroy()
    return;
#_______________________________________________________________#LoadingPage#__________
load = Image.open("Logo.png")
render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
img = Label(SWH,image=render)
img.image = render  
img.place(x=458,y=250)

load = Image.open("PoweredByServiceWhiz.png")
render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
img1 = Label(SWH,image=render)
img1.image = render  
img1.place(x=362,y=612.5)

img.after(5000, removewidgets(img, img1))
```

Comment: Hmmm. Continued to work on this and ive kinda worked the function out but its not "professional" i suppose. Still interested in other peoples knowledge on this subject. However, concerning the img.after(5000) This, like time.sleep() waits the time before opening the window, how do i make it open the window then wait the time?

Answer (score 2):

First, when you're numerating your variables, you should use something else instead, in this case, a list, so you just have to pass a single list to the function. In the function, you can loop over the sequence items and call `destroy` for each of them. It would be even easier if you'd create a class for the GUI.

The thing is that you *call* the function `removewidgets` *inside* the `img.after` parameter. Since all callable parameters are called and their return value is used, your calling the event `None`.
Use this construct instead:

```
img.after(5000, lambda: removewidgets(img, img1))
```

`lambda` creates an anonymous function, thus you're using the *function object* as the parameter.

You don't need to type `return;`, btw. If there's no `return` specified, the function will return `None`.

Comment: Alrighty, Thanks :) Im going to further look into using a list in the function and probably look into creating a class if you say its easier. And the Lambda, works perfectly, going to read about it now. Never heard of it before now so im glad you mentioned it :) Learning everyday haha. Cheers :)

Comment: Well, if you use a class directly, you can forget about the parameter story and access the attributes directly inside the class. In this case, you can just use `img.after(5000, self.removewidgets)`.

Comment: Alright, i will look at using classes but it'll have to wait till tomorrow :( Going out now. Thanks for the help, much appreciated and il let you know how i get on with this. Ta :)

Comment: Urrgg... Been trying to learn classes through multiple sites and videos and so far have been able to follow the tutorials but im struggling to utilize this new knowledge and bring it into my own code.